# How to request a form which was made by a list from an external file in python and HTML? Brings up werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

Tags: python, html, forms, for-loop, python-requests

I am trying to make a website which receives the users answers in the form of radio buttons. I have made the radio buttons with a for loop, and thought that my python code would be able to receive the users answers with a for loop too! I'm very new to this so it's most likely something tiny that I've done wrong.

I think it might be because inside the for loop, I have put a `request.form[word]` and maybe the request.form doesn't get the parameters that I've put in the calculate function? Apart from that I've already tried this and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've included the relevant parts of my python code, the txt file, the html file for the test page and the error which shows up on my screen.

**Python Snippet**

```
# imports flask, a function which can redirect the current url
# to a different one, and url_for
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
import copy

# creating the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "aC@nth8scdjkfdhfjdsfkdksm12345678910helloworlddlrowolleh"


# when you click on the link, it directs to this page
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/home")
def tohome():
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


# makes a list of the questions
firstpage_questions = list()
with open("firstquestions.txt", "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        firstpage_questions.append(i.rstrip("\n"))

# this deep copy is so if I make any changes to the duplicated list it won't affect the original list.
firstquestions = copy.deepcopy(firstpage_questions)

questlist = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)


# the request method means that if the sight reloads, the user still has their results saved
@app.route("/takethetest", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def takethetest():
    return render_template("takethetest.html", q=firstquestions, answers=questlist)


def calculate(firstq, lastq):
    for word in firstquestions:
        for num in questlist:
          answered = request.form['question ' + str(questlist[num-1])]
          mental_issue = 0
          if firstquestions.index(word) >= firstq and firstquestions.index(word) <= lastq:
            if firstquestions.index(word) % 2 != 0:
              mental_issue += int(answered) * 10
            elif firstquestions.index(word) % 2 == 0:
              mental_issue += (10 - int(answered)) * 10
            else:
              continue
          else:
            break
        #     make this an error handling thingy which posts it onto the website.
        return mental_issue


@app.route("/results", methods=["POST"])
def results():
    if request.method == "POST":
        burn_out = calculate(1, 5)
        stress = calculate(6, 10)
        anxiety = calculate(11, 15)
        return render_template("results.html", b=burn_out, s=stress, a=anxiety)
    else:
        return render_template("results.html")
        

# runs the app, and debug=true means that it reloads the page without
# having to load it on this virtual environment


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Txt File Snippet**

```
Over the past month, have you been procrastinating more than ever? 1 for nope, 10 for yes too much!
In the last month, how often have you sat down and properly relaxed? Choose 1 for once, and 10 for I relax all the time.
Have you eaten more/less in the past month? From one to ten how much have your eating habits changed?
Do you have perfectionistic tendencies? If yes, pick 1. If you don't care at all that something is screwed up, pick 10.
In the past ten days, how many days have you been completely exhausted and lost all motivation?
How many days in the past ten days have you been having no problem falling asleep, or waking up completely refreshed?
On a scale of one to ten how much do you worry or are nervous about an upcoming social situation?
How many days in the past two weeks have you NOT noticed your heart racing randomly? 1 for heart racing all the time, 10 for not noticing.
How many times a day do you get easily irritated by other people/things? From 1 to 10.
Do you ever feel ‘on edge’ or unsettled? 1 for all the time, 10 for no.
How many times have you felt like you’ve been on ‘low power mode’ in the last two weeks? 1 for 1 day or less, 10 for 10 days or more.
How many days in the past two weeks has your skin been normal (no extra pimples, sores etc.)? 1 for my skin has been so bad, to 10 for perfect skin.
Have you ever caught yourself clenching your jaw or grinding your teeth in the past month? 1 for never, and 10 for all the time.
In the past month, have you had a normal digestive routine, with no irregularities such as diarrhoea and constipation? 1 for never, and 10 for nothing wrong with my bowels.
Have you bitten your nails, fidgeted with your phone, or showed any nervous behaviours more frequently in the past two weeks? 1 for 1 day or less, 10 for 10 days or more.
```

**HTML Take The Test File**

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Take the Test{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vh-100">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>About The Test</h3>
            <p class="blue">This test will ask you if you seem to have any of the different symptoms of burn out, anxiety and extreme
                stress. Consider these questions as abnormal things you usually don’t do – like if you usually
                procrastinate and know it’s part of your personality, think if you have procrastinated more than usual.
                This test has been designed for teenagers, but is suitable for all ages. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="blue">Test questions</p>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="blue">More test questions</p>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="blue">Your Results</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vh-500">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <form action='/secondtestpage' method='POST'>
            <ol>
                {% for qnum,qtext in enumerate(q) %}
                    <li>{{qtext}}</li>
                    <label>{% for anum,atext in enumerate(answers) %}
                    {{atext}} <input type='radio' value='{{anum}}' name="question{{qnum}}"/>
                        {% endfor %}</label>
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value=" Next Page "/>
            </ol>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**Error That Comes Up**

```
burn_out = calculate(firstquestions, 1, 5)
File "/Users/arimulligan/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/hello.py", line 47, in calculate
    return render_template("takethetest.html", q=firstquestions, answers=questlist)
 
 
def calculate(first_list, firstq, lastq):
    for word in first_list:
        answered = request.form[word]
        mental_issue = 0
        if first_list.index(word) >= firstq and first_list.index(word) <= lastq:
            if first_list.index(word) % 2 != 0:
                mental_issue += int(answered) * 10
            elif first_list.index(word) % 2 == 0:
File "/Users/arimulligan/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 377, in __getitem__
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'Over the past month, have you been procrastinating more than ever? 1 for nope, 10 for yes too much!'
```

If you would like to know anything else about this feel free to ask! And sorry in advance if my code is messy.

Comment: You haven't shown us any of the Python code.  It's not really smart to set the `<input>` tag name to the whole question, because that's the name that will be used for the variable in the response.  You should use names like `question1`, or something that's usable as a variable name.

Comment: @TimRoberts I Just realised and put in all of my code now :) I have now used the input tag name as `'question {{answers[number-1]}}'` and updated the code to fit this, thank you. However, it still comes up with the same error

Comment: But you have to include the question number in there as well.  Have you looked at the HTML you're generating?  You need to do that, because it is not what you think it is.  Your radio box elements should have names like `question-1-3`, which is answer #3 for question #1.  And remember, when you do  `for number in answers`, `number` will be THE ANSWER, not the index of the answer, which is what you seem to think.  You may need to use `for qnum,question in enumerate(q)` and `for anum,answer in enumerate(answers)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should generate usable HTML.  Then, your `secondtestpage` will receive elements like `question0` with a value of `1` for answer #1 to question #0.  Add 1 to those if you want.

```
        <form action='/secondtestpage' method='POST'>
                <ol>
                    {% for qnum,qtext in enumerate(q) %}
                        <li>{{qtext}}</li>
                        <label>{% for anum,atext in enumerate(answers) %}
                        {{atext}} <input type='radio' value='{{anum}}' name="question{{qnum}}"/>
                            {% endfor %}</label>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input type="submit" value=" Next Page "/>
                </ol>
            </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes more sense :) But whenever I run the code, it still comes up with this error: `line 85, in results burn_out = calculate(0, 4)
line 52, in calculate: answered = request.form['question' + str(qnum)]
in __getitem__ raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'question0'` This could be because of my python code? How would I change that?

Comment: That says it didn't find `question0`.  Did you fill out all the questions?  You can use `if 'question'+str(qnum) not in request.form:` to check if it's there.

Comment: I figured it out! I was using the POST method to another html page, not linking the take the test file! Which is why it couldn't find the question0 because the other html page didn't have question0 on it's form. Thank you for your help :)